# Traverse JSON object from jQuery AJAX using string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to store the traversal path of JSON in a variable beyond the first level?

Define the JSON traversal path in variables.

```
var jsonPathLink = 'sequenceId'; 
var jsonPathText = 'answer.body';
```

jQuery AJAX call. (I removed all unnecessary settings, but let me know if you would like any more code included.)

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(data){
    if(data.length > 0){
      for(x in data){
        console.log(data[x][jsonPathLink]); // This works.

        console.log(data[x][jsonPathText]);  // This does not work.
        console.log(data[x] + jsonPathText); // This also does not work.
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You could use eval, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: You would probably need to parse them out, which should be trivial using regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could write a traverseObject-function like the following:

```
function traverseObj(obj, path) {

    var arr = path.split('.'),
        len = arr.length,
        i = 0,
        ret;

    for ( ; i<len; i+=1 ) {

        // on the first iteration, the passed object
        // is cached in the ret-variable.
        ret = !i
            ? obj[arr[i]]
            : ret[arr[i]];

    }

    return ret;

}
```

the single elements of the path are applied to the passed obj, by iterating over them. the result is cached and returned.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/k8GWz/

Comment: super little script... did similar but not quite as neat and optimised... Think i might need to include array traversal as well.
e.g. myObj.anotehrObj.anArray[0].something.  Will post when done it!